# How the .getTime() can preserve the original date dd/MM/yyyy?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, date, datetime

I have a trouble. I have an angular Javascript application that is storing the dates in mysql with milliseconds, but in some moments the date is interpreted with one more or less day. For example:

If the user selects in the date picker: 03/02/2017, the application is saving this (in milliseconds) as 02/02/2017 or 04/02/2017. I believe it is due to the timezone. This is the way I'm using to convert the date in milliseconds:

```
var temp = $("#datetimeField").val().split("/");                
var newDatetime = new Date(temp[2], temp[1] - 1, temp[0]).getTime();
```

As you can see, I know the day, the month and the year before store it in the database. Normally the date is stored and works well, but in some moment the date changes as I showed above. How can I always get `temp[2]/temp[1]-1/temp[0] ???` from the stored milliseconds?

Comment: JavaScript date objects are created in browser/user timezone. You can use JavasSript `Date` object's `toUTCString()` method to convert the date to UTC (presumably) before sending it to the server. This way all dates sent to server will be UTC and you will not have to worry about client timezone.

Comment: @Ejaz I will try!, thanks!

Comment: The milliseconds **are** UTC. Using *toUTCString* is just a different representation of exactly the same date and time. If you want an ISO 8601 compliant string, use *toISOString*, not *toUTCString*.